# Creating new data.frame considering a dummy variable for period and a third variable

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dummy-variable

Using this data (*corrected)

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1461, 1826, 2191, 2557, 2922, 
3287, 3652, 4018, 4383, 4748, 5113, 5479, 5844, 6209, 6574, 6940, 
7305, 7670, 8035, 8401, 8766, 9131, 9496, 9862, 10227, 10592, 
10957, 11323, 11688, 12053, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13514, 13879, 
14245, 14610, 14975, 15340, 15706, 16071, 16436, 16801, 17167, 
17532, 17897), class = "Date"), State = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Duration = c("", 
"", "", "", "5", "", "2", "1", "", "", "3", "", "2", "", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "", "", "3", "", "", "", "4", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "10", "1", "", "2", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "8")), row.names = c(NA, -46L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to reach this new data.frame:

```
newdf <- data.frame(State = c("Expansion", "Contraction", "Expansion", "Contraction", "Expansion", "Contraction",
                             "Expansion", "Contraction", "Expansion", "Contraction", "Expansion", "Contraction",
                             "Expansion", "Contraction", "Expansion"),
                   Duration = c("5", "2", "1", "3", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "3", "4", "10", "1", "2", "8"),
                   Period = c("1974 - 1978", "1979 - 1980", "1981", "1982 - 1984", "1985 - 1986", "1987 - 1988", "1989",
                              "1990", "1991", "1992 - 1994", "1995 - 1998", "1999 - 2008", "2009", "2010 - 2011", "2012 - 2019"))
```

Dummy equal to one would return "Expansion" (zero, "Contraction"). I guess the column Duration could be used to get the initial date and final date.

Comment: What does the `State` column represent?

Comment: It's a dummy variable that indicates "Expansion" (=1) or "Contraction" (=0).

Comment: Then why is it always equal to 1?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I corrected the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an option with `tidyverse`.  Convert the 'Date' to `Date` class, extract the `year` from the 'Date', create a grouping column based on the occurrence of numeric values in 'Duration', after grouping by 'grp', `summarise` by taking the `last` value of 'Duration', while `paste`ing the `first` and `last` of 'year' if there are more than one row in 'grp' or else return the `first` 'year' and similarly, change the 'State' to a single value 'Expansion/Contraction' if `all` the 'State' are 1 or 0

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date), 
           year = year(Date),
       grp = lag(cumsum(str_detect(Duration, "\\d+")), default = 0)) %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    summarise(Duration = last(Duration), 
              Period =if(n() > 1) str_c(first(year), last(year), sep=' - ') else
          as.character(first(year)), 
       State = if(all(as.logical(State))) 'Expansion' else 'Contraction' ) %>% 
    select(State, Duration, Period)
# A tibble: 15 x 3
#   State       Duration Period     
#   <chr>       <chr>    <chr>      
# 1 Expansion   5        1974 - 1978
# 2 Contraction 2        1979 - 1980
# 3 Expansion   1        1981       
# 4 Contraction 3        1982 - 1984
# 5 Expansion   2        1985 - 1986
# 6 Contraction 2        1987 - 1988
# 7 Expansion   1        1989       
# 8 Contraction 1        1990       
# 9 Expansion   1        1991       
#10 Contraction 3        1992 - 1994
#11 Expansion   4        1995 - 1998
#12 Contraction 10       1999 - 2008
#13 Expansion   1        2009       
#14 Contraction 2        2010 - 2011
#15 Expansion   8        2012 - 2019
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's perfect!